# Dynamically resizing of d3.js bar chart based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a set of bar charts that will be updated dynamically with json data.

There will be occasions where the x.domain value is equal to zero or null so in those cases I don't want to draw the rectangle, and would like the overall height of my chart to adjust. However, the bars are being drawn based on data.length which may contain 9 array values, but some of those values are zeros, but render a white space within the graph.

I've attached an image of what is happening. Basically there are 9 data entries and only one of those actually contains the positive value, but the bars are still being drawn for all 9 points.

Here is my code:

```
d3.json("data/sample.json", function(json) {

var data = json.cand;

var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 0
}, width = parseInt(d3.select('#graphic').style('width'), 10),
width = width - margin.left - margin.right -50,
bar_height = 55,
num_bars = (data.length),
bar_gap = 18,
height = ((bar_height + bar_gap) * num_bars);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select('#graphic').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin['left'] + margin['right'])
    .attr('height', height + margin['top'] + margin['bottom'])
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin['left'] + ',' + margin['top'] + ')');

     var dx = width;
     var dy = (height / data.length) + 8;


// set y domain
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.receipts;
})]);
y.domain(0, d3.max(data.length))
    .rangeBands([0, data.length * bar_height ]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(2)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return '$' + formatValue(d);
    });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .ticks(0)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return '';
    });
// set height based on data
height = y.rangeExtent()[1] +12;
d3.select(svg.node().parentNode)
    .style('height', (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + 'px');

// bars
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data (data, function (d) {
    if (d.receipts >= 1) {
            return ".bar";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .enter().append('g');

bars.append('rect')
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return 0;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        if (d.receipts >= 1) {
        return i * (bar_height + bar_gap - 4);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .attr("width", function(d, i) {
    if (d.receipts >= 1) {
            return dx * d.receipts;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });



//y and x axis

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis bottom')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis.orient('bottom'));

svg.append('g')
    .call(yAxis.orient('left'));

});
```

[image]

Comment: I would filter the data and remove those items that you don't want to draw before passing it to D3.

Comment: How would you suggest doing that? Via the domain?

Comment: No, filter the data itself. That is, remove all elements you don't want to draw from the array of data.